# How to create a VTK project in Windows Form Project (VisualC++ 2012 )

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, vtk

I'm trying to embed scene created with Visualization ToolKit (VTK)library into VisualC++ 2012 created windows form so I can design my Windows native GUI interface.

I'd like to underline that, all examples with console app are configured with (Cmake), compiled with VC++2012 and works flawlessly, as instructed by the official VTK wiki page.

The issue is, if I try to call those VTK functions and class initializations inside of Win Form application I get the `Error LNK1107: invalid or corrupt file: cannot read at 0x2E0 D:\.....\VTK_61_BUILD_VS2012\bin\Debug\vtkViewsCore-6.1.dll` even if I add everything normally as expected, include headers and external library dependencies.

This makes me think that I'm originating from wrong Visual C++ 2012 project template or something obvious that I'm completely missing, otherwise compiler would arise many not found files or syntax error.

This is the first lines where I'm trying to invoke the VTK library, even the intellisense suggest the vtk..... named proc,functions and structures, but application fails to compile.

```
#pragma once

#include <vtkSmartPointer.h>
#include <vtkTriangle.h>
#include <vtkCellArray.h>
#include <vtkPolyData.h>
#include <vtkRenderWindow.h>

namespace CLR_Project1 {
using namespace System;
using namespace System::ComponentModel;
using namespace System::Collections;
using namespace System::Windows::Forms;
using namespace System::Data;
using namespace System::Drawing;
...
...
vtkSmartPointer<vtkPoints> points = vtkSmartPointer<vtkPoints>::New();
```

What is the problem here ?

Comment: first you must create a clr wrapper for VTK or use C++/CLR mixed mode .

Answer (score 1):

The following link (in particular the answer of Mr. bnsteel) helped me very much, when I had the same problem ==>

http://vtk.1045678.n5.nabble.com/VTK-and-Winforms-integration-td5721086.html

You can use Swig as it is suggested under the link. But it is not necessary. Using the similar way (passing the windows form panel handle) you can create a C++/CLI wrapper as jalal sadeghi proposed. You will pass the panel handle through the wrapper to your C++ library that does all the "VTK work". This way you don't have to create individual wrappers for all VTK classes, all the "VTK work" and dependencies on VTK stay hidden in your C++ layer.

Something like this ==>

C++ side

```
setImageRenderWindowParentID(void *theID){ 
        ... (init your vtk render window) 
        renWin->SetParentId(theID); 
}
```

C++/CLI side

```
void setRenderWindowParentID(IntPtr parentID, .. also pass the panel size .. ){
    void* p = parentID.ToPointer();
    myCPPVTK->setRenderWindowParentID(p, .. also pass the panel size ..);
}
```

C# side

```
 VTKWrapper.setRenderWindowParentID(m_panel.Handle, .. also pass the panel size ..);
```